# How to handle query timeout for Snowflake jdbc?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are using JDBC driver to connect to Snowflake and perform inserts. Using setQueryTimeout on preparedStatement to get the desired timeout behavior. Auto commit is kept default i.e. enabled.

We are observing, On timeout driver tries to cancel the query, however query still committing data into table.
Below is the sample program which uses 1 second as timeout for quick reproducible scenario -

```
boolean flag = false;
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into Test_Int values (?)");
ps.setQueryTimeout(1);
for (int v =1; v<200; v++) {
    ps.setInt(1, v);
    ps.addBatch();
    flag = true;
    if(v%50 == 0) {
        try {
            ps.executeBatch();
            flag = false;
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //do not stop execution continue with other batches
        }
    }
}
if(flag) {
    try {
        ps.executeBatch();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
            //do not stop execution continue with other batches
    }   
}
```

As per requirement, we are continuing with next batch on SQLException, and all data get committed into table eventhough there is timeout.

Questions - 
How does timeout work? 
Is there any retry or connection renewal also done by driver in this case? 
If the driver initiate cancel command, would query cancellation on DB guaranteed with rollback or it depends? 
How to handle timeout-related exceptions in better way in the code?

Thanks you for the help in advance.

Comment: Hi Sam, time out will be set in the Snowflake environment. I would check your timeout parameters referenced here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#statement-timeout-in-seconds I would take a look at this approach for a large or continuous connection: old example: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-ingest-java/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/ingest/example/SnowflakeIngestBasicExample.java https://community.snowflake.com/s/scripts

Comment: Thank you Rachel McGuigan for your response and information. However, in our usecase, we need long running queries to timeout and able to handle the exception, basically timeout at query level and hence setQueryTimeout. It can be SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE query. Observation is JDBC driver issues cancel command, still data is committed every time that means query is not cancelled at DB level, however JDBC driver issues SQLException to client program with SQL State 57014. Looking for more understanding and better way to handle this in JDBC program. Thanks.